# Install M.2 SSD on laptop when there is no slot for it

Tags: laptop, ssd, dell-inspiron, m.2, m2-connector

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 3567 which, like the official website says, doesn't have an M.2 slot, and the only solution is to replace my already installed HDD with a SATA SSD, which I don't wanna do. And I've seen that in desktops, it's possible to *add* an M.2 slot, but it ain't possible on laptops.

So is there any kind of "hacks" to be able to install an M.2 SSD on my laptop?

Comment: You will be always limited by the SATA port, don't think there is another way out

Comment: Why would you not pick a SATA SSD which you can properly mount when the M.2 won't provide any benefit and to the contrary probably will make it more difficult to use the laptop? You might be able to find some USB adapters or similar if you really want to use a M.2 SSD (at even lower speeds).

Comment: @Seth The problem is that if I use a SATA SSD, I need to unmount the HDD from the motherboard, because there's no enough space. By the way I'm gonna use the SSD to install another operating system, so external SSD isn't a solution

Comment: Which is why you would replace the HDD with a larger SSD? I still don't see what the problem would be with that? An M.2 would take space as well and if you can't fit an additional HDD you won't be able to fit an M.2 either.

Comment: @Seth If I replace my HDD, I would need to backup a lot of stuff (I know I should do it anyways but I don't) and reinstall all the stuff, log into my accounts again, etc. Right now I won't be going for this option except if I can't find any other solution. And another reason is budget, I'm a minor so my budget is very limited...

Comment: Ask yourself the following questions: Where do you have space within your laptop chassis to put an M2 if you want to keep your HDD? What size of M.2 do you have; how does it compare to the size of a 2.5 inch drive? What kind of performance do you expect and what connectors does your laptop have available to attach another device (USB, SATA, something else)? To replace the disk you could always (try) to image it using a boot CD/boot stick and just transfer the image to a new disk. You could also get a USB enclosure or similar to still have access to the data. You will need a USB or SATA adapter

Comment: Have you considered using an SD Card instead? Performance won't be stellar, even with faster SD Cards, but for exploring a new operating system, that probably isn't your primary concern. Another option could be replacing the optical drive win another SSD. If that option is available, you would still have to use a normal SATA SSD, as optical replace enclosures will generally use that connection.

Comment: @SBI But, booting from an SD card, that doesn't sound very simple to do. I think there's only these solutions: an SD card, an SSD enclosure, or use a USB adapter. I will look at each one and choose. Thank you all.